# Getting the right configuration of an HC component with an LED

Tags: led, current

I am using an 74HC299 shift register and would like an LED on each of the 8 outputs.  The LED I chose is the SML-LX1206YC-TR.  I have a 100ohm resistor in series with each of the LEDs and each are tied to one of the 8 outputs. The LEDs seem to light initially but eventually fade away, I'm guessing as the chip warms up.

The LED has a forward current 30mA with a peak current of 60mA and a forward voltage of 2V. I'm guessing this is way to much for an output of the 74HC299 to drive.  Now that I am looking at the data sheet on HC components I'm thinking they can only drive around 4mA in the high state.

So, what is the correct chip to add between my 74HC299 and the LED to drive it properly?

Note my entire design is based on using the HC(T) family of chips.

Comment: Look under their absolute maximum ratings. You will find a total for the supply current. This is the MAXIMUM you can be allowed for ALL of your LEDs. They will also specify there a maximum "per" output. That is yet another limitation. You don't have to guess. Just get the datasheet and read it. Also, you don't want to operate near the absolute max ratings. Whose 74HC299 did you actually buy? (All manufacturers will likely say the same thing -- but that's not solid. It's possible to have different specs [which I've seen for the 2N2222 BJT, for example.])

Comment: The 74HC299's are from NXP.

Comment: Their datasheet, Table 4, says you are pretty much not going to drive your LEDs (not all of them, anyway) without external support. So you are probably right that their thermal shutdown kicks in. Good thing, too.

Comment: Yep, what's the correct external support approach typically.  A chip which is just an array of transistors?

Comment: Nothing is "correct." It's really a matter of your own call. But whatever you do, you should limit each output to about a maximum of \$3\:\text{mA}\$ with this device so that the sum of all the output sink/source stays well under the limits. This would be about a 10:1 ratio for the \$30\:\text{mA}\$ LED current you mentioned, which is right at the \$\beta=10\$ for a saturated BJT switch. So that's good. (Well, unless you really wanted more LED current.) But you can also find LED driver/buffer ICs, too. So whether discrete or IC is your call. And if discrete, you have various options there.

Comment: Or you can use something like this: [8-Bit Shift-Register LED Driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slis177/slis177.pdf).

Comment: Awesome I’ll take a look at this chip as suggested

Comment: If you look around more, you'll even find 8-bit shift register LED driver ICs that ***also*** will support programmable current limits (either with an external resistor -  just one - or else internally with registers you can set and configure.) So you could reduce the resistor count, as well. And some of them will even include the ability to program in PWM duty cycles, as well. And some will support RGB LEDs, too, with separate voltage rails for each color. This whole area has a great many choices. LEDs, if you have a lot to drive, need very complicated support. So ICs abound.

Comment: I’m thinking something like this might be pretty Straightforward. http://www.me-sh.cn/products/pdf/m54513p_e.pdf

Comment: With more than 1000 mcd per mA possible, unless you need blinding indicators there  is no need to choose weak poor chips. https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/cree-inc/C503B-RAS-CA0C0AA1/C503B-RAS-CA0C0AA1-ND/6561759